# Remove an action from init in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a theme that defines a new post type but I want to remove that function in the child theme:

**PARENT THEME FUNCTION:**

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio_register');

function portfolio_register()
{
//post type definition
}
```

**CHILD THEME FUNCTION:**
This is what I tried but it is not working.

```
function child_remove_parent_function() {
    remove_action( 'init', 'portfolio_register' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'child_remove_parent_function', 15 );
```

Anyone has an idea of what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code before add action in child theme function.php

```
<?php
remove_action( 'init', 'portfolio_register' );   
?>
```

or

```
<?php
add_action( 'after_setup_theme','remove_portfolio', 100 );

function remove_portfolio() {
    remove_action( 'init', 'portfolio_register');
}
?>
```

Comment: it works! So the problem was in the action priority?